# Impulse Responses with 68% confidence interval

Tags: time-series, econometrics, vector-autoregression

In my field some papers are published with questionable econometric methodology.

The impulse responses are presented with 68% confidence bands only and the conclusion is that the effect is significant. I am wondering if there maybe is a statistical/econometric reason why the 68% interval can be used in the VAR context?

I don't know of a single other test which would accept a hypothesis not less than 0.9. Why is the VAR literature different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

68% roughly represents a confidence interval with half-length one standard deviation. I believe that the use of this in macroeconomics can be attributed to Christopher Sims and Tao Zha. Here is [an excerpt from one of their papers](http://sims.princeton.edu/yftp/imperrs/m4Web.pdf):

> Also, for characterizing likelihood shape, bands that correspond to
>   50% or 68% posterior probability  are  often  more  useful  than  95% 
>   or  99%  bands,  and  confidence  intervals  with  such low  coverage 
>   probabilities  do  not  generally  have  posterior  probabilities 
>   close  to  their  coverage probabilities.

The paper "Unconventional Confidence Bands in the Literature on the Government Spending Multiplier" by Ryan Murphy ([link here](https://ideas.repec.org/a/ejw/journl/v12y2015i1p72-83.html)) discusses exactly this issue at length.